# Regex search function only working on the first column, and only works on the second or later word for other columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following search function for a dynamically generated table based on json data. The search function is:

```
var $rows = $('#toolsTable tr:not(:first)');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
```

An example of the table is:

```
Name | Description | Source | Comments
-----|-------------|--------|--------------------
John | Test one two| Reddit | Here is the comment
Jay B| One try here| Stack  | Second comment
```

When I search for `John`, it works perfect. When I search for `Test`, it filters everything and does not work, but when I search for `one`, only the first row of data (John's row) shows up, as opposed to both. This is because the search is only working for the second word or later for every column outside of the first (Name). If I were to type `Reddit` or `Stack`, nothing would show up. Any help on understanding this is greatly appreciated. I am quite new to Javascript and web dev in general! Thanks!

EDIT: Not exactly sure why, but adding debouncing functionality actually fixed it.

Comment: Can you not filter with a much simpler `$(this).text().indexOf(searchTerm) === -1` test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the same issue, adding a debounce function fixed this, and not exactly sure why...perhaps it was loading too fast? :).

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
var timeout;
return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
}

$('#search').keyup(debounce(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
}, 150));
```